# Can someone explain exactly what happens if an exception is thrown during the process of allocating an array of objects on the heap?

Tags: c++, exception, new-operator

I defined a class foo as follows:

```
class foo {
private:
   static int objcnt;
public:
   foo() {
       if(objcnt==8)
           throw outOfMemory("No more space!");
       else
          objcnt++;
   }

   class outOfMemory {
   public:
       outOfMemory(char* msg) { cout << msg << endl;}
   };

   ~foo() { cout << "Deleting foo." << endl; objcnt--;}
};
int foo::objcnt = 0;
```

And here's the main function:

```
int main() {
    try {
            foo* p = new foo[3];
            cout << "p in try " << p << endl;
            foo* q = new foo[7];
        }catch(foo::outOfMemory& o) {
           cout << "Out-of-memory Exception Caught." << endl;
        }
}
```

It is obvious that  the  line "foo* q = new foo[7];" only creates 5 objects successfully, and on the 6th object an Out-of-memory exception is thrown. But it turns out that there's only  5 destructor calls, and destrcutor is not called for the array of 3 objects stored at the position p points to. So I am wondering why?  How come the program only calls the destructor for those 5 objects?

Comment: If the array p points to is not on the heap, where does it reside then?  I think by declaring the array p like foo p[3], you actually declare it on the stack. Once a exception is thrown, it is natural that those 3 objects will be destroyed during stack unwinding.

Comment: Note the array pointed at by p is not on the Stack (only the pointer p). If you had declared the array p on the like this: `foo p[3];` Then those three would also be destroyed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Destructors are only called for the fully constructed objects - those are objects whose constructors completed normally. That only happens automatically if an exception is thrown while `new[]` is in progress. So in your example the destructors will be run for five objects fully constructed during `q = new foo[7]` running.

Since `new[]` for the array that `p` points to completed successfully that array is now handled to your code and the C++ runtime doesn't care of it anymore - no destructors will be run unless you do `delete[] p`.

Comment: @sharptooth: Thank you very much for your answer! You said that C++ runtime doesn't care of p anymore once it is successfully completed. Does that mean once an exception is thrown and the program goes out of the scope of p, p is simply destroyed whereas the memory it points to will not be taken care of by the c++ runtime?

Comment: @rialmat: Exactly. Once `new[]` finishes normally your code becomes responsible for managing the array lifetime. `p` is a raw pointer and it has a trivial destructor, so when it goes out of scope (normally or due to an exception) it will be formally destroyed, but that destruction will do nothing to the pointed to array and the array will leak.

Answer (score 7):

The "atomic" C++ allocation and construction functions *are* correct and exception-safe: If `new T`; throws, nothing leaks, and if `new T[N]` throws anywhere along the way, everything that's already been constructed is destroyed. So nothing to worry there.

Now a digression:

What you **always** must worry about is using *more than one* `new` expression in any single unit of responsibility. Basically, you have to consider any `new` expression as a hot potato that needs to be absorbed by a fully-constructed, responsible guardian object.

Consider `new` and `new[]` strictly as library building blocks: You will never use them in high-level user code (perhaps with the exception of a single `new` in a constructor), and only inside library classes.

To wit:

```
// BAD:
A * p = new A;
B * q = new B;  // Ouch -- *p may leak if this throws!

// Good:
std::unique_ptr<A> p(new A);
std::unique_ptr<B> q(new B); // who cares if this throws
std::unique_ptr<C[3]> r(new C[3]); // ditto
```

As another aside: The standard library containers implement a similar behaviour: If you say `resize(N)` (growing), and an exception occurs during *any* of the constructions, then *all* of the already-constructed elements are destroyed. That is, `resize(N)` either grows the container to the specified size or not at all. <sub>(E.g. in GCC 4.6, see the implementation of `_M_fill_insert()` in `bits/vector.tcc` for a library version of exception-checked range construction.)</sub>

Comment: Or even better and what the OP is actually trying is local array objects.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I don't think the OP has real code; I think that is test code deliberately designed to explore `new[]`...

Comment: I disagree he explicitly talks about an array on the heap and does not talk about new, the OP writes about creating an array (that just happens to use new). And what is more real than compilable code?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Actually i do know it's bad practice to have raw pointer in the code, and it's better to use RAII instead. But thank you very much for the advice anyway. You are right about the intention of the code. It is intended to explore new[] and exception in C++. Actually what i wanted to ask is why *p may leak if an exception is thrown on the second new.

Comment: @rialmat: Because `p` is lost when the scope exits through the exception, so there's no way to destroy and deallocate `*p`. The whole point of RAII is that you always have this invisible magic around that will call the *destructor* whenever a scope exits. If you think about the C++ program flow, there's a ton of magic going on under the hood that would be extremely tedious and unscalable to write out by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You get the behavior you expect when you declare the arrays on the heap:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo   p[3];
        cout << "p in try " << p << endl;
        foo   q[7];
    }
    catch(foo::outOfMemory& o)
    {
       cout << "Out-of-memory Exception Caught." << endl;
    }
}
```

In your code only the pointers were local automatic variables. Pointers don't have any associated cleanup when the stack is unwound. As others have pointed out this is why you generally do not have RAW pointers in C++ code they are usually wrapped inside a class object that uses the constructor/destructor to control their lifespan (smart pointer/container).

As a side note. It is usually better to use std::vector than raw arrays (In C++11 std::array is also useful if you have a fixed size array). This is because the stack has a limited size and these object puts the bulk of the data in the heap. The extra methods provided by these class objects make them much nicer to handle in the rest of your code and if you absolutely must have an old style array pointer to pass to a C function they are easy to obtain.

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<foo>     p(3);
        cout << "p in try " << p << endl;
        std::vector<foo>     q(7);

        // Now you can pass p/q to function much easier.

    }
    catch(foo::outOfMemory& o)
    {
       cout << "Out-of-memory Exception Caught." << endl;
    }
}
```