# What happen if exception's thrown during allocation?

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following function template:

```
template<typename T>
void init(std::vector<T>& v, int min, int max)
{
    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        v.push_back(new T());
}
```

which will use from another function as follows:

```
void foo()
{
    std::vector v;
    init(v, 10, 20);
    //something else
}
```

what happens if some exception is thrown during initialization of some object of type `T` in the function `init`?

Do I get memory leak in that case or some other kind of UB? If so, how can I prevent it?

Comment: `std::vector<T>& v` ... `v.push_back(new T());` .. This won't even compile. Is this vector containing pointers or actual instances?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168203/can-someone-explain-exactly-what-happens-if-an-exception-is-thrown-during-the-pr?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

If memory allocation fail, you will get `std::bad_alloc` exception. If there is exception during execution of construction of type T, that should be handled in constructor of type T using try catch block.

If `std::vector::push_back` failed  after creation of object using `new` operator, there is a possibility of memory leak since newly generated raw pointer is not yet part of the vector.Since you are creating a vector of raw pointers generated using `new` operator, and you should call `delete` over the contents of vector as part of proper clean up. `std::vector<>` destructor only cleans up the pointers but not objects  of type T.

To resolve this raw pointer issue, you can depend on `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` in place of raw pointer if you have C++11 compiler

Comment: Not neccesary. What if the constructor can throw something else?

Answer (score 4):

> Do I get memory leak in that case or some other kind of UB?

Assuming that `T` is well-behaved<sup>*</sup>, you will not get a memory leak, and behavior is fully defined.

C++ standard guarantees that it will run the destructor of `std::vector<T>`, cleaning up the memory that has been allocated to that vector. Moreover, C++ standard guarantees that if an exception is thrown by a `push_back()`, the function has no effects, meaning that your vector remains safe to destroy.

<sup>*</sup> By well-behaved I mean that `T` should deallocate resources associated with it. A common example of `T` that is *not* well-behaved is a plain pointer: it wouldn't take care of cleaning up.

Comment: __C++ standard guarantees that it will run the destructor of std::vector<T>__ not clear. If `new T()` in the push_back fail why the entire vector will be destroyed?

Comment: @stella I mean the destructor of `v`, when the exception is propagated from `init` to `foo`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight there is a possibility of memory leak since vector is  of raw pointers and vector destructor will take care only deleting the raw pointers not exact objects mapped to the raw pointers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight:  `v` is just a reference.  When it goes out of scope, the vector persists.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Of course I mean `v` inside `foo`, not `v` inside `init`.

Comment: It seems like this answer may be missing the point.  It doesn't address the allocation of the memory that was allocated for the instance of T that failed to construct, nor does it acknowledge that the raw pointers that may already be in the vector point to memory that will be leaked when the vector is destroyed.  The latter is forgivable, since the code in the question won't actually compile, so we don't really know if stella intends to put raw pointers in the vector or not.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy A note acknowledging the problem with raw pointers has been added 20 minutes before your comment. Please refresh the page if you do not see the edit.

Comment: There's a difference between `T` being a pointer type and the vector holding `T *`s.  The original question has still not been clarified in that respect.  Regardless, the gist of the question seems to revolve around the `new T`, which allocates memory then executes the constructor.  It's worth pointing out that if the constructor throws, that memory will be freed before the exception is propagated out.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `new T()` typically does two things:

1. Allocate memory for a T
2. Construct the T in that memory

If the constructor throws an exception (and something up the stack is handling exceptions), then the memory that was allocated in step 1 will be freed before the exception is propagated up the stack.  No memory leak here.

Answering what happens at the next level up requires having the code in the question clarified, because the type of the vector doesn't match its usage.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is thrown, it will recover your functions calls until it reach a `try` `catch` block.

If there is no try catch between this call and your main, your program will exit with an error value.

You can manage it like that:

```
std::vector v;

try
  {
    init(v, 10, 20);
    // Init was successful, continue execution here
  }
catch (const std::exception& exception)
  {
    // An exception was thrown in init or after
    std::cerr << exception.what() << std::endl; // Print exception error message
  }
```

Anyway, your vector won't be affected by any memory leak **if you declare it before your try-catch block**.

Comment: So I shouldn't worry about leaks if I wrap the call to init into try-catch. I just get not completely initialized list, right?

Comment: @stella true, but usually, when an error occur with a simple allocation, something very wrong is hapening on the computer and you should stop your program.